# GCC for x86: Optimize sum of two couples of floats

Tags: gcc, simd, avx, avx2

I am compiling the code below, with optimization, and it still looks like there would be a more efficient way of performing the two sums using SIMD capability of the underlying hardware. What would be the right mix of flags for GCC to generate assembly that loads operands in couples and executes the two additions in a single instruction?

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    float val[2];

    foo(float a, float b)
    {
        val[0] = a;
        val[1] = b;
    }

    foo& operator+=(
            const foo &rhs)
    {
        val[0] += rhs.val[0];
        val[1] += rhs.val[1];
        return *this;
    }
};


int main(void)
{
    volatile float values[] = { 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 7.0 };
    foo first(values[0], values[1]);
    foo second(values[2], values[3]);

    second += first;

    std::cout << "(" << second.val[0] << ","
            << second.val[1] << ")" << std::endl;

    return 1;
}
```

The assembly code that is generated looks like this (for the operator+() alone), where seems pretty apparent that all operands are treated individually.

```
  400712:   c5 fa 10 4c 24 14       vmovss 0x14(%rsp),%xmm1
  400718:   c5 fa 10 5c 24 10       vmovss 0x10(%rsp),%xmm3
    foo second(values[2], values[3]);
  40071e:   c5 fa 10 44 24 1c       vmovss 0x1c(%rsp),%xmm0
  400724:   c5 fa 10 54 24 18       vmovss 0x18(%rsp),%xmm2
        val[1] += rhs.val[1];
  40072a:   c5 f2 58 e8             vaddss %xmm0,%xmm1,%xmm5
        val[0] += rhs.val[0];
  40072e:   c5 e2 58 e2             vaddss %xmm2,%xmm3,%xmm4
        val[1] += rhs.val[1];
  400732:   c5 fa 11 6c 24 0c       vmovss %xmm5,0xc(%rsp)
        val[0] += rhs.val[0];
  400738:   c5 fa 11 64 24 08       vmovss %xmm4,0x8(%rsp)
```

I compile with this command (but removing -mavx2 does not change the result much):

```
g++ -O3 -mavx2 -g -std=c++11 main.cpp -o run
```

In case it matters, this is GCC 6.3 (and do not really have the freedom to upgrade).

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to convince GCC to auto-vectorize `float[2]` expressions. You could do this manually using intrinsics if you really need to: https://godbolt.org/z/aj9aJY

Comment: Gcc vectorization of statements works from the end: it looks for a place where you store elements contiguously, and checks if they may come from similar operations. Here you pass each scalar separately to functions, gcc doesn't see any opportunity to vectorize.

Comment: Also, `volatile` is interpreted as "please don't optimize anything around here".

Comment: @MarcGlisse I think the most relevant fact here is that GCC does not vectorize operations which just work on two floats. If you apply `operator+=` on two consecutive `foo` objects, it does vectorize (after adding a `__restrict__`): https://godbolt.org/z/iYTZHt

Comment: @chtz They did some work for gcc-10 to start using SSE registers for MMX-sized operations, but apparently not enough :-( Try -Dfloat=int to see that it does work sometimes...

Comment: Thank you! The suggestion of using intrinsics works, but when it is all said and done and optimized in the context of the real code, the operation takes 1 more instruction than not vectorizing -- probably because of some re-aligment of addresses. It sounds like a good reason to not vectorize by default for such small vectors :)
`__volatile__` is there just to prevent constant propagation, which indeed would wipe out the whole behavior in this specific example.

Comment: @MichelePetracca To avoid constant propagation, better put the code you want to analyze/test in a non-inlined function. `volatile` is amongst the most misused C/C++ language features ...

Comment: @MarcGlisse I guess in general, it is not too trivial to use SSE for two floats, since depending on what operations you are doing you may end up with operations like `0.0f/0.0f`, which could have unwanted side-effects, if the MXCSR is set badly. Or on some CPUs working with NaNs/Infs/SubNormals may slow the execution down more than the gain from using SIMD. For integers this is obviously not a problem.

Comment: @chtz: any luck with intrinsics getting GCC to emit `movsd` 64-bit loads of 2 floats?  To feed `addps` (with the high elements zero-extended from the movsd loads; this is why you don't want `movlps` loads).  `movlps` stores are fine though, and save code size over `movsd`.  I guess the issue with intrinsics is whether the cast to `double*` violates strict aliasing when you use it with an intrinsic that loads 2 floats.  Stupid intrinsics API should have just used `void*` from the start; they only figured that out in time for AVX512, and I don't think they redid the old ones.

Comment: @PeterCordes In my first comment I linked how to force a `movsd` load using some brutal casting -- I agree this very likely violates strict-aliasing, but so does any meaningful use of `_mm_loadu_si128` or `_mm_loadl_epi64`. And I assume this will likely hinder gcc from making better optimizations for loops over multiple `foo` objects.

Comment: @chtz: `__m128` and `__m128i` are defined with `__attribute__((may_alias))` so they're like `char*`.  Compilers are required to define this behaviour.  ([Is \`reinterpret\_cast\`ing between hardware SIMD vector pointer and the corresponding type an undefined behavior?](//stackoverflow.com/q/52112605)).  But `double` is just plain `double`.  But if there's no deref, only passing it to a GCC built-in, it *might* still be fine.

Comment: If casting to `__m128i` is fine, one could of course use `movq`/`_mm_loadl_epi64` (clang replaces them by `movsd`): https://godbolt.org/z/tyBgvF